# SVN commit - internet drops - laptop hibernates - after turning on commit continues

Tags: svn

1. Commiting large filebase to SVN.
2. Laptop hibernates internet drops of.
3. Turn on laptop, reconnect to internet.
4. Commit continues as if paused.

I was expecting it to fail. Should I be worried and start checking data integrity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion is designed such that any commit is *atomic*. Either the entire commit succeeds, or the entire commit will fail. There is no such thing as a partial commit. Updates are also atomic, so you will never get only part of a commit that is in progress either. Thus nobody else should have data corruption or anything, either.

Check the repository to make sure your revision exists, but other than that I think you'll be fine.

For what it's worth, I'd also have expected this to fail. It's kind of cool that it doesn't, actually.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I read the same about atomic commits. But the situation at hand made me doubt it. Anyways. Thanks!